# How to repeat a letter number of times between two strings

Tags: javascript, recursion

I am trying to add a string 'a' on between another string 'Bat' repeatedly with the help of recursion but seems it doesn't work. I know to use .repeat() but I want to try it with recursion

```js
function repeat(n){
  let str = '';
  if(n <= 0){
  return 'B' + str + 't';
  }else{
  str += 'a'
 return str+= repeat(n-1)
  }
}

console.log(repeat(5))
//What I want -- 'Baaaaat'
//What I get -- 'aaaaaBt'
```

Comment: There are better ways to do this than recursion.  But if that's what you want.  Imagine you have repeat(4) = "Baaaat".  How do you turn that into repeat(5) = "Baaaaat".  You're adding an "a" at the beginning.  You want to add the "a" after the first character.

Comment: If you don't care about recursion, this is just `"B" + "a" * n + "t"`. Python allows you to multiply strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to keep track of `str` between function calls. You could do this by storing the value of `str` in `this` using `Function.prototype.bind`, by adding an additional `str` parameter, or by using a global variable.

```js
// Using Function.prototype.bind
function repeat_bind(n) {
  const str = this.str ?? '';
  if (n <= 0) return 'B' + str + 't'
  return repeat_bind.bind({ str: str + 'a' })(n - 1);
}
console.log('bind: ' + repeat_bind(5));


// Using additional parameter
function repeat_param(n, str = '') {
  if (n <= 0) return 'B' + str + 't'
  return repeat_param(n - 1, str + 'a');
}
console.log('parameter: ' + repeat_param(5));


// Using pre-existing global variable
let str = '';
function repeat_preglobal(n) {
  if (n <= 0) {
    const result = 'B' + str + 't';
    str = '';
    return result;
  }
  str += 'a';
  return repeat_preglobal(n - 1);
}
console.log('pre-existing global: ' + repeat_preglobal(5));


// Using ghost global variable (created and deleted)
function repeat_ghostglobal(n) {
  const str = window.str ?? '';
  if (n <= 0) {
    delete window.str;
    return 'B' + str + 't';
  }
  window.str = str + 'a';
  return repeat_ghostglobal(n - 1);
}
console.log('ghost global: ' + repeat_ghostglobal(5));
```

In my opinion, out of all of these options, using an additional parameter is the cleanest method to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using another wrapper function around the recursive function, so that the `B` and `t` can be added separately from the `a`s:

```js
const repeatA = n => 'a' + (n === 1 ? '' : repeatA(n - 1));
function repeat(n){
  return 'B' + repeatA(n) + 't'
}

console.log(repeat(5))
```

If you wanted to do it in a single function, you could have the *final recursive call* return `Bt`, then have the upper calls insert an `a` after the first letter:

```js
function repeat(n){
  const str = n === 0 ? 'Bt' : repeat(n - 1);
  return str[0] + 'a' + str.slice(1);
}

console.log(repeat(5))
```